# C++ function calling to 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have in class County.h constructor:

```
struct Country {
    Country(double**, int);
};
```

and in main I have `graph[Size][Size]` and I want to call the constructor for `County`.

```
int main() {
    double graph[Size][Size];
    Country c(graph, 0);
}
```

But its giving me error `no matching function for call to ‘County::County(double [22][22], int)’`

What I can do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried casting the graph as such: County c((double **) graph, (int) size); ?

Comment: An array of arrays is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @JoeUrc I doubt reinterpreting the `double`s as pointers will lead to anything useful.

Comment: @JoeUrc: Bad idea. Hacking around errors makes you do silent errors.

Comment: Any reason why you do not use a `vector<vector<double>>` ?

Comment: @tobi303 because nested vectors are evil.

Comment: @Quentin why are they evil? When it is about passing or returning them to/from function, c-style arrays are nasty, but whats the problem with nested vectors?

Comment: @tobi303 Avoiding C-style arrays is good. Nested vectors however bring another set of problems : their rows can change length implicitly, and they are real cache-busters. Sadly the standard library does not provide multidimensional dynamic arrays, but Boost.MultiArray is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double [Size][Size]` and `double**` are not at all the same type. That is what your compiler doesn't like.

Change your constructor prototype or the way you declare your array. But you cannot directly cast an array of array to a pointer of pointer.

```
struct Country {
    Country(double[Size][Size], int);
};
```

OR:

```
int main() {
    double** graph = new (double*)[Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        graph[i] = new double[Size];
    }
    Country c(graph, 0);

    // Don't forget to delete your graph then.
}
```

Note that the first one requires that you would know the size before your code start its execution (storing `Size` in a macro for instance), but the second one is longer to code, and you will have to manipulate more RAM memory, that can lead to mistakes if you are not careful.

Comment: i think i created like your first solution but I didn't give Size

Comment: @Saif If in your Country.h, you coded your constructor taking a `double **` parameter, it's not at all like if you just didn't gave a Size: It is a different variable type. A valid constructor here would be taking a `double [x][x]` with `x` in a Macro.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to declare your constructor as a template and pass the array by (`const`) reference,

```
struct Country {
    template<size_t N>
    Country(double /*const*/ (&arr)[N][N], int);
};
```

In this way, the template will deduce the size of the array directly. Of course, the downside is that the above won't work with double pointers. The upside is that the compiler will strongly check the type and your program won't even compile if the array is not made of `double`s (no conversions are being performed at type deduction) or if it is not square.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is, that it links pretty much everything that has to handle this array together into one compilation unit. But, yes, it seems to be the best that C++ can do. In that regard it's clearly inferior to C...

Comment: @cmaster I guess that's the price to pay for enforcing type safety.

Comment: @cmaster have to say I'm not very familiar with pure `C`. So you'd write the such function like `void f(int m, int n, int x[m][n]){}` and pass the dimensions? (I think you need at least to pass the dimensions). The problem is that it will allow passing arrays of different sizes and types (at least on my machine `gcc` only spits an warning).

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea. Unfortunately, I have to realize that you are right, `gcc` does not check the types. I would guess that that's a deficiency of `gcc`, not of the standard, but I may be wrong. Theoretically, it would be possible to do all the required type-checking (you don't need to know what value an array size has to assert that two array types derived from the same variables are the same), but it does add quite a bit of compiler complexity, and VLAs are not the most heavily used feature.